# msi installer for website folder in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using **visual studio 2012**. I have a folder with some aspx web pages. I want to generate an **web setup(msi installer) project** for the folder I have. I can do this using web setup project template in **visual studio 2008**. But how to generate **msi installer** in **visual studio 2012**. Is there any template to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a [Web Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I went through [Web Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx) but it won't create .msi.Please refer [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/visual-studio-create-setup-project-to.html)